# Custom paragraph-start and paragraph-separate for editing *.srt files

Tags: paragraphs

I'm having some trouble coming up with regular expressions for variables `paragraph-start` and `paragraph-separate` to do what I want (to be defined shortly). I'm editing `*.srt` files (subtitles for school lectures) and trying to set my variables so that `M - }` and `M - {` take me up and back one block of text for editing. The file has the following format:

```
1
00:00:16,040 --> 00:00:23,130
Some text here that marks the beginning       <--
of a block.

2
00:00:23,390 --> 00:00:28,230
(Speaker): And some more                      <--

3
00:00:28,230 --> 00:00:32,350
text here that also marks the                 <--
beginning of another block. There
could be multiple sentences in here.
```

I want to set variables `paragraph-start` and `paragraph-separate` in such a way that `M-{` and `M-}` (paragraph back and forward) take me between the beginning of the lines marked with `<--`.

I tried to set `paragraph-separate` to `".*-->.*"` (since the arrow never appears in the subtitles text) and `paragraph-start` to match any after this line, but `M-}` always seems to place me **on** the timestamps line (the one including the `-->`), although I want to go to the line **after** it.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong and how I can set the variables `paragraph-start` and `paragraph-separate` appropriately?

Answer (score 0):

The following code will probably do what you want.

Note that it will change globally `M-{` and `M-}`.

I would use an [hydra](https://github.com/abo-abo/hydra) for this (assuming that I would use also other functions during file editing).

```
(defun adl/srt-backward-paragraph ()
  (interactive)
  (backward-paragraph 2)
  (if (= (point) (point-min))
      (next-line 2)    
    (next-line 3)))

(defun adl/srt-forward-paragraph ()
  (interactive)
  (forward-paragraph)
  (while (= (char-after) 10) (next-line))
  (next-line 2))


(global-set-key (kbd "M-{") 'adl/srt-backward-paragraph)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-}") 'adl/srt-forward-paragraph)
```